# EF6 Database First Table-per-Type multiplicity issue on foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I am fairly new to EF, so I hope this isn't a stupid question.  I searched, but couldn't find anything relative to my issue.

I've been having issues modeling an existing database in EF6.  I have TPT inheritance setup as follows:

[TPT model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8upE.png)
I have to manually add the BAMS*Environment tables due to issues creating the model.  Everything is fine until I add the Foreign key from BAMSPortalEnvironment to BAMSPrimeEnvironment.  For a given Prime environment, there may or may not be a Portal environment, but for every Portal environment, there is a Prime environment.
I get the following error from VS2017:

> Running transformation: Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'BAMSPortalEnvironment' in relationship 'FK_BAMSPortalEnvironment_BAMSPrimeEnvironment'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be *.

Simplified model of the relevant tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Environment(
  EnvironmentId     int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  EnvironmentTypeId char(1) NOT NULL,
  [Description]     varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT UQ_Environment UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (EnvironmentId ASC) ON [PRIMARY],
  CONSTRAINT PK_Environment PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EnvironmentId ASC, EnvironmentTypeId ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];

CREATE TABLE dbo.BAMSPrimeEnvironment(
    EnvironmentId       int NOT NULL,
    EnvironmentTypeId   AS CAST('B' AS char(1)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_BAMSPrimeEnvironment_Environment FOREIGN KEY (EnvironmentId, EnvironmentTypeId) REFERENCES dbo.Environment (EnvironmentId, EnvironmentTypeId) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT PK_BAMSPrimeEnvironment PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EnvironmentId ASC, EnvironmentTypeId ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];

CREATE TABLE dbo.BAMSPortalEnvironment(
    EnvironmentId       int NOT NULL,
    EnvironmentTypeId   AS CAST('P' AS char(1)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    BAMSPrimeId         int NOT NULL,
    BAMSPrimeTypeId     AS CAST('B' AS char(1)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_BAMSPortalEnvironment_BAMSPrimeEnvironment FOREIGN KEY (BAMSPrimeId, BAMSPrimeTypeId) REFERENCES dbo.BAMSPrimeEnvironment (EnvironmentId, EnvironmentTypeId) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT FK_BAMSPortalEnvironment_Environment FOREIGN KEY (EnvironmentId, EnvironmentTypeId) REFERENCES dbo.Environment (EnvironmentId, EnvironmentTypeId) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT UQ_BAMSPortalEnvironment_BAMSPrimeId_BAMSPrimeTypeId UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (BAMSPrimeId ASC, BAMSPrimeTypeId ASC) ON [PRIMARY],
    CONSTRAINT PK_BAMSPortalEnvironment PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EnvironmentId ASC, EnvironmentTypeId ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

I can "fix" this by changing the "0..1" to "*", but that does not accurately describe my model.  What am I missing to get this working?

This is my first post, so if you need additional information, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it help if you apply a unique constraint on `BAMSPrimeEnvironment`, something like this
`CONSTRAINT UQ_EnvironmentID_EnvironmentType UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (EnvironmentId ASC, EnvironementType) ON [PRIMARY],`

Comment: I don't understand the suggestion.  The table already has a primary key on those columns, which is unique.  AFAIK, EF6 does not support unique constraints, only primary keys.

Comment: Oh, sorry i did not notice that you already had a *composite* PK on *both* of these columns, I thought it was only on `EnvironmentId`. That is very strange, in both tables you have composite PKs so this relationship is clearly `0..1` and not `*`. Maybe EF just does not support such scenario, and treats every FK as a one to many implicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution, so instead of BAMSPortalEnvironment referencing BAMSPrimeEnvironment, I changed it to reference Environment instead, which resolved this issue.